# difference wnen running nmap as sudo

Tags: nmap

I'm experimenting with nmap and i am trying to find my android phone on my local network from my laptop. I know the phones local IP is 192.168.2.2, and when i run

```
nmap -sn 192.168.2.2
```

it finds it

```
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up)...
```

but when i just add sudo in front of it, it says

```
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up)...
```

Why does it find my phone when i ping it as a regular user, but not when i ping it as root? And am i missing some crucial knowledge to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run as `sudo` with elevated privileges in order to allow `nmap` to create raw sockets, otherwise `nmap` defaults to using default probing which is sending SYN packets to ports 80 and 443 using the connect system call:

Read more answers here:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74493/different-results-using-nmap-with-without-sudo
- https://superuser.com/questions/887887/different-behavior-sudo-nmap-vs-just-nmap